# unable to verify the first certificate node.js and axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to use an API that generates slips, but it has a ssl verification problem, I have the certificate, but I can't use it, my code is in NODE.JS with Express and Axios.

I'm trying to generate the token but it doesn't work, it returns unable to verify the first certificate and I'm not sure what to do anymore.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require ('express');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/obtemToken", async (req, resp) =>{
    try {
        
        //the certificate is inside that RAIZ file
        const caCert = fs.readFileSync('RAIZ_AAA Certificate Services.pem');

        const authUrl = "https://oauth.sandbox.bb.com.br/oauth/token";

        const clientId = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        const clientSecret = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        
        const requestBody = querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        });
    
        const response = await axios.post(authUrl, requestBody, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },

            ca: caCert,
           
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
            
            const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
            resp.json({ accessToken });
        }
         else {
            console.error("Erro ao obter token 1: ", response.data);
            resp.status(response.status).json({ error: 'Erro ao obter o token' })
    
         }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao obter token: ', error.message);
        resp.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao obter o token' });
    }
});

app.get("/listarBoletos/", async (req, resp) =>{
});

app.post("/gerarBoleto/", async (req, resp) =>{
});

app.get("/detalheBoleto/:id", async (req, resp) =>{
});

app.patch("/alterarBoleto/:id", async (req, resp) =>{
});

app.post("/baixaBoleto/:id/baixar", async (req, resp) =>{
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("servidor iniciado na porta 3000: http://localhost:3000");
 });
```

[image: my files are organized like this]

I want to generate the authentication token to follow up on using the api